# Which one of the following is NOT a haloalkane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, halides

> Which one of the following is NOT a haloalkane?
>
> A) Freon
> B) Teflon
> C) Iodoform
> D) Vinyl chloride

Every compound here seems to me as a haloalkane: Freon, Teflon, iodoform, and vinyl chloride.

My text says the answer is vinyl chloride, but how?

Comment: Hint: they certainly all contain halogens, but what is an alkane?

Comment: What is the structure of vinyl group?

Comment: One of these things is not like the others
One of these things just doesn't belong
Can you tell which thing is not like the others
By the time I finish my song? Sesame Street

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have went through each option:

A) Freon is $\ce{CCl2F2},$ which is derived from methane

B) Teflon is a polymer of $\ce{-F2C-CF2 -}$ (or) $\ce{(C2F4)_n},$ derivative of 1,2-difloroethene. Here, carbon is saturated, which means no double or triple bond is present.

C) Iodoform is $\ce{CHI3},$ which again is a derivative of methane.

D) Vinyl chloride is unsaturated thus it does not classify as an halo*alkane*.